# Display static images with url from dict in template

Tags: django

I'm having some trouble displaying my images if the url value comes from a dict.

if I do below it works.

```
{% for key, values in images.images.items %}
    <div class="imageBox">
        <img src="{% static 'images/ka/1.jpg' %}" alt="My image" width=100% height=100%/>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

But I'd like to use the url values from the dict iteration instead. Like below

```
{% for key, values in images.images.items %}
    <div class="imageBox">
        <img src="{% static '{{values}}' %}" alt="My image" width=100% height=100%/>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

value

```
{{values}} = 'images/ka/1.jpg'
```

But this dosen't work even tho `{{values}}` is `'images/ka/1.jpg'` like the previous example. If I inspect the html in my browser it shows the src is `/static/%7B%7B%20values%20%7D%7D`. Why is it different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `{{ }}` inside `{% static %}` tag.
Try this:

```
{% for key, values in images.images.items %}
    <img src="{% static values %}">
{% endfor %}
```

This should work.

Comment: That did it! Can't believe I didn't try that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `get_static_prefix` template tag like so:

```
<img src="{% get_static_prefix %}{{ values }}" alt="My image" width=100% height=100%/>
```

`get_static_prefix` populates a template variable with the path specified in your `STATIC_URL`.

Reference [get_static_prefix](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#get-static-prefix)

Comment: That gives me a 'get_static_prefix', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?. Do I need to change something in settings?

Comment: Did you end your `for` loop afterwards?

Comment: Also you need to `{% load static %}` at the top of your page